# How do I import my error_handler module into my app.py in flask?

Tags: python, flask, web, backend

I separated my flask errorhandlers into a separate module called 'error_handlers.py' within my 'app.py' directory. I have tried importing the error_handlers module into the app module but i keep getting an ImportError:

> ```
>     from app import app
> ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)
> ```

I looked up a similar question and added blueprint but i'm still getting the same error. Please is there anything I'm doing wrong. My code below:

**app.py**

```
import os

from error_handler import *

from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp

from helpers import lookup, login_required

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(error_handlers.blueprint)
...
```

**error_handlers.py**

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, Blueprint

blueprint = Blueprint('error_handlers', __name__)


@blueprint.app_errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
return render_template("errors/404.html")
```

Comment: `from app import app` change either the directory name or the file name

Answer (score 1):

Hey you are getting `Circular Import Error` so change the name of your file or the function name must be different from the file name. 
By this way, the compiler won't get confuse what the function to call.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I got what you meant by 'the function name must be different from the file name' but I changed the file name and i'm still getting the same error